# How to prove statistical hypothesis?

Tags: probability, statistics

I developed a caching method. I took 100 experiments and got that hit ratio is not less than 75%. Now, I want to prove that my method with some probability gives hit ratio not less than 75%. How should I make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the chance of a type I or type II error in your hypothesis, which is essentially what you are looking for, the probability that your hypothesis is incorrect:

If you are running a Bernoulli trial, which I'm assuming you are, your hypothesis is that p>=0.75 where P(x=0)=1-p P(x=1)=p

type I error occurs when your hypothesis was actually correct but you rejected it based on your expirements. Since the criteria you are using to determine if you reject or accept the hypothesis is whether or not your expirements gave a successful result in over 75% of the time, the chance for type I error is:

P(sum(1 through 100)(x)<75 | p>0.75)

type II error occurs when your hypothesis was incorrect, but you accepted it:

P(sum(1 through 100)(x)>75 | p<0.75)

The sum of the results of Bernoulli trials have a binomial distribution, so you can calculate these probabilities using the CDF/PDF of the binomial distribution, which can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I couldn't give you a vote, because I don't have enough reputation :(